# Python keeps getting corrupted and requiring reinstallation

Tags: python, conda, corruption, miniconda

I'm on windows 10 and using Miniconda 64bit version 4.9.2. For some reason my python installation keeps getting corrupted after running scripts, sometimes it will happen randomly, other times it seems like specific scripts cause it to become corrupt. This doesn't happen to my other teammates though who are running similar environments.

What will happen is after trying to run a specific script or command (jupyter lab for example) that worked previously that day, I will randomly get an error with something like the following:

```
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

Usually it seems to involve a library I'm using in the stack trace, but I don't think it's a specific library because it will be different ones in the stack trace from time to time, I'm guessing whatever got corrupted at that moment. I've tried deleting the pycache files for the specific libraries that error out, but that shows me what I think is the root of the problem, files are getting corrupted and overwritten with random characters. See an example error stacktrace below after deleting .pyc files and attempting to run again:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\miniconda3\envs\environment\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\user\miniconda3\envs\environment\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\users\user\miniconda3\envs\environment\Scripts\jupyter.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\miniconda3\envs\environment\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import paths
  File "c:\users\user\miniconda3\envs\environment\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 15, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "c:\users\user\miniconda3\envs\environment\lib\tempfile.py", line 832
    self._rmtree(ȕ&�n�gH�6�
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

When I look in the file after getting this error, it literally has been cut off and random characters like those seen above have been inserted. This never happens in the middle of scripts though, it's only after something has run and I try to run it again or I try to run something else afterwards. Not sure what's going on I'm not super versed in python. It's getting to the point where I have to reinstall multiple times a day.

Is it just my system? I'm using pycharm as my IDE, would that have anything to do with it? I'm gonna try different versions of miniconda but not sure if that will do much. I haven't found much support for this issue through my research.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using Miniforge (python 3.7.10, conda 4.10.3, windows 10).
Last line of the .py files of some modules gets randomly corrupted.

I noticed that in addition to `lib` content, also all the .py files in `pkgs` subfolders are already corrupted, but the compressed files in tar packages are fine.

I found this temporary workaround:

- delete the cached files in `lib\brokenmodule\__pycache__`
- delete the source folder in `pkgs\brokenmodule-version-build\`
- run `conda update brokenmodule --force-reinstall`